# Typewriter JS, How to delete chars in Fast being type chars in Normal as it is

Tags: javascript

I am using Typewriterjs on my website from this link. https://safi.me.uk/typewriterjs/.
It Types chars at normal speed and Removes in Normal speed. I want to remove chars in "Fast speed". But I don't know which function is handling this scenario. Please help.

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
  loop: true
});

typewriter.typeString('Hello World!')
  .pauseFor(500)
  .deleteAll()
  .typeString('Strings can be removed')
  .pauseFor(500)
  .start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TypewriterJS/1.0.0/typewriter.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a speed parameter into the `deleteAll()` method.

```js
const instance = new Typewriter('#typewriter', {
  loop: true,
});

instance.typeString('Hello world!')
  .pauseFor(1000)
  .deleteAll(15)
  .typeString('Another message here...')
  .pauseFor(1000)
  .start();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/typewriter-effect@2.4.0/dist/core.js"></script>
<div id="typewriter"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate to @[James Coyle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1994081/james-coyle)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54400654/3783478), you can set `deleteSpeed` as a part of config to override the default delete speed.

By default, it is set between `50-150`ms:

```js
this.default_options = {
  strings: false,
  cursorClassName: 'typewriter-cursor',
  cursor: '|',
  animateCursor: true,
  blinkSpeed: 50,
  typingSpeed: 'natural',
  deleteSpeed: 'natural',
  charSpanClassName: 'typewriter-char',
  wrapperClassName: 'typewriter-wrapper',
  loop: false,
  autoStart: false,
  devMode: false
};

.....

if (delete_speed == 'natural') {
  delete_speed = self._randomInteger(50, 150);
}
```

---

Sample:

```js
var app = document.getElementById('app');

var typewriter = new Typewriter(app, {
  loop: true,
  deleteSpeed: 10
});

typewriter.typeString('Hello World!')
  .pauseFor(500)
  .deleteAll()
  .typeString('Strings can be removed')
  .pauseFor(500)
  .start();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/TypewriterJS/1.0.0/typewriter.min.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
```